# Bundle an ELF within a Rust application

Tags: linux, rust

I want to bundle some static ELF's as part of my Rust application, specifically [bubblewrap](https://github.com/containers/bubblewrap) and bash. Instead of the user having to manage these files out-of-band, everything would be bundled into a single file.

I don't know if there is any crate for this. What I have already tried [in this repo](https://github.com/viperML/bundle-rs/blob/master/src/main.rs) is:

- Bundling the file with `include_bytes!`
- Creating a `/dev/shm` memory mapping + `std::ptr::copy_nonoverlapping`
- Try to execute `/dev/shm/file` directly

I am getting some `EBUSY` errors, so instead of trying to investigate this further, I wonder if there is any other method or crate that already handles this use case.

Comment: As far as I have tried, it is hardly possible to implement this, especially when the application is supposed to work on both macOS and Linux

Comment: The application is not supposed to work on macOS, as I mentioned ELF specifically. And only x86_64 Linux for the matter.

Comment: Why not write out the file to a [`tempdir`](https://crates.io/crates/tempdir), then try to execute that?

Comment: I don't think you cannot `exec()` a file that is writable elsewhere. I think the proper error would be `ETXTBUSY` but then, it is not exactly the error scenario documented in `man execve`. You can try unmapping that from your program or maybe mapping it as read-only, if you are not doing that already.